# Please review the migration of this Jetson's Foley Artist sound question

Tags: discussion, migration

After seeing [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55664/what-produces-the-sound-of-transportation-non-canon) on SF&F, I'd like to have my own Foley Artist question remigrated here. I posted [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/3758/what-did-they-use-to-make-the-jetsons-flying-car-sound-effects) in SF&F when I was relatively new to the site and unfamiliar with Meta. It was quickly migrated over to Movies.SE where it remains without a concrete answer. Although it is centered on a cartoon, it is a sci-fi cartoon and I feel it is better suited here in SF&F.

I'm looking for a group consensus. Your comments are welcomed.

Comment: Questions can't be migrated if they're over 60 days old. It's not going anywhere.

Comment: @Kevin Any thoughts on re-posting it here?  That was my original suggestion in the comments over there (since I figured the 60 days applied)

Comment: @Kevin But this isn't a migration, it's a rejection of a migration.  I know that if the receiving site closes a migrated question soon after it's migrated, it rejects the migration.  Dunno if that's still true at this point.

Answer (score 1):

(A late answer, but)

Based on what is on-topic *now*, it shouldn't have been migrated.

That having been said, it's now *way* past the 60 day limit for either emigration or (I'd imagine) re-immigration. So your best bet would be re-asking, possibly linking to the cross-site duplicate and noting that you haven't received a satisfying answer over there so far.